# How to prevent input of null enter in C#

Tags: c#

I have just started a table programme. I am just a trainee learning C# from internet, so I am not so good in this.

I just wanted the programme to run according to the user. I want that if the user hits enter simply, the programme should not crash. That is I just wanted to know how to prevent null enter. This is the code is used:

The "______" which used if for writing a line

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tables
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        goto found;
        found:
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string textToEnter = "MULTIPLATION TABLES";
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (textToEnter.Length / 2)) + "}", textToEnter));
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        int num, j, i;
        Console.Write("enter the number of which table u need ? :- ");
        num = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine());
        while (num == 0)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a valid input");
            Console.Write("enter the number of which table u need ? :- ");
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.Write("enter the number till which the table need to be ? :- ");
        j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (j == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a valid input");
            Console.Write("enter the number till which the table need to be ? :- ");
            j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        i = Convert.ToInt32(j);
        for (j=1; ; j++)
        {
            if (j > i)
            {
                break;
            }
                Console.WriteLine(num + " * " + j + " = " + num * j);
        }
        string str;
        Console.Write("do you want to continue? (y/n) :- " );
        str= Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (char ch in str)
        { 
        if (ch == 'y')
        {
            goto found;
        }
        else if (ch=='n' )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("THANK YOU FOR USING MY PRODUCT");
        }
        else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter a valid input");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can try getting the content in a String, and then checking if the string is null or empty before trying to parse it to an int. Or you could try adding your code to a try/catch so you can handle some exceptions

Comment: Use [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you're accepting user input, it's important to perform *validation* on it. You can't assume that the user will always enter correctly formatted data that your program will be able to work with. As you discovered, a user who hits enter will give you an empty string (`""`), which can't be parsed to anything.

C# has several ways of attempting parsing. The first, which you're using, is `Convert.ToInt32()`, which throws an exception if the input it receives is not, in fact, a number. You have to catch the exception with a `try`/`catch` block, like so:

```
try
{
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch(FormatException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a proper number!");
}
```

However, in general, exceptions should be, well, *exceptional*. They should only be relied upon when rare failures occur, because unwinding the call stack can be expensive.

I would argue that C# has a better method for you to use in this instance: `Int32.TryParse()`

You can see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1).

`TryParse` takes two parameters, the thing you're trying to parse (convert), and then a number to store the value in. It returns true or false, indicating if it succeeded or failed in converting the number.

You might use it like this:

```
var success = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), num);
if (success)
{
    // do something with 'num' -- it has a valid value now.
}
else
{
    // Warn the user, perhaps prompt them to try again
    Console.WriteLine("That wasn't a valid number!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, I'd use [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__), but inside a [do...while()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do) loop.  Use a separate flag (boolean) to track whether the user should keep trying again:

```
bool invalid;
int num, j, i;

do
{
    invalid = true;
    Console.Write("enter the number of which table u need ? :- ");
    String response = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(response, out num))
    {
        invalid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please try again.");
    }
} while (invalid);

// ...repeat the above do...while() block for "j" and "i"...
```

Comment: and please say why did you add invalid true at the top and again invalid = false..
actually I understood what tryparse does but I didn't understand what {if, else} and  
{do , while} is doing here...

Comment: The `if...else` is so that you can determine if the number entered was a valid integer.  If true is returned by `int.TryParse()`, then a valid integer was entered and "invalid" is set to false allowing the `do...while` loop to exit.  If false was returned, then the `else` block allows us to display a message to the user telling them as such.  The code posted by PinBack is slightly shorter because there is no message telling them the input was invalid; it simply goes straight back to asking for another input.

Comment: The `invalid = true` at the top of the `do...while` loop is actually not necessary for this block of code.  But note at the bottom I had a comment that said: repeat the above do...while() block for "j" and "i".  If you copied and pasted that exact block, changing out "num" for "j" and then "i", it would still work because "invalid" would be reset for each block.  Without that line, "invalid" would still be false from the previous user entry, and the `do...while` loop could theoretically exit after the user entered an invalid input.

Comment: The `do...while` loop itself is what prevents the user from moving on until they have type in a valid integer.  The loop just keeps going back and asking for another value as long as the "invalid" flag is set to true.

Comment: oh...thank you so much for helping and explaining...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a methode to get a safe int value:

```
private static int ReadIntValue(string psMessage)
{
    int lnInt;
    string lsValue = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(psMessage);
        lsValue = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (!int.TryParse(lsValue, out lnInt));
    return lnInt;
}
```

And then use this:

```
            num = ReadIntValue("enter the number of which table u need ? :- ");
```